# Install Ubuntu / on SSD and /home on HDD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, nautilus, ssd, home-directory

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my computer. I have an SSD and an HDD. I want to install the Ubuntu root `/` on my SSD (and my swap too), but install my `/home` on my HDD.

I didn't find how to do it during the Ubuntu install, so I installed Ubuntu on my SSD and I'm trying to move `/home` to my HDD.

What I have done:

Created an ext4 partition for my newHome with GParted.
Then `sudo mount /dev/myNewPartition /media/stockFolder`
Then `sudo cp -av /home/. /media/stockFolder`

I'm in trouble because Alt+F2 and `gksudo nautilus` don't work (`command not found`), but I need it to rename `/home` in `/oldHome` and then `mkdir /home` and mount `/dev/myNewPartition /home` and `cp -av /media/stockFolder/. /home`

If there is a solution to do it during installation it would be nice. Please help me to run `gksudo nautilus`?

Comment: Yes I have seen this post but even if pkexec nautilus works, rename home already return : This item could not be renamed : device or resource busy

Comment: So which is the question, here? That you can't invoke `gksudo nautilus`, or that the home folder is busy? Or that you want to know how to set your destination `$HOME` directory on another disk? Because your `$HOME` will always be busy if you're logged in, so you'll need to try after booting from a "live cd" and opening a shell session with `Super`+`Alt`+`T`. Then you can run `sudo apt-get install gksu` as root, you can install whatever you need and it won't affect your actual OS fyi.

Comment: I just want to install /home on another disk. One way is to move /home. It still doesn't work. I understand that I need to be out of ubuntu to do something on /home. But even if I run ubuntu on my usb key, I can't install gksu or nautilus-admin. It makes no sens. I tried with this : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving but also impossible to move /home for same reasons and if I'm running from usb key /home on my disk is empty.

Comment: Have you tried this?: https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-ubuntu-with-different-root-home-hard-drives/

Comment: "If I'm running from usb key /home on my disk is empty." You're looking in the wrong place. Of course it's empty, you want to be looking on the drive where your `/home` should be! You can use `udisksctl` to mount the partition and go from there: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/mounting-hard-disks-partitions-using-linux-command-line/

Comment: The title is a mismatch with body ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution

Finally I **reinstalled ubuntu following this example** : [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/343352#343352)
but the point is that you can create a root partition on SSD and a /home partition on HDD **even if you have the device for boot selected as SSD** - like the step 8 of this example.

For **those how want to move /home** the best solution is here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving
and keep in mind you can't rename /home when you are on your ubuntu session. To do it boot on an usb key and you can use `udisksctl` to mount the partition and go from there: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/mounting-hard-disks-partitions-using-linux-command-line/

Thank you for your comments, they really help me to understand how it works.

I hope it will help someone !